# Custom gridview with asp.net and boostrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, post, gridview

I am doing an interdisciplinary work in college which would be a simple POST system, using gridview and bootstrap/asp.net, so far it has worked out fine, but I am in the part of SHOWING the post on the home page, and the gridview is not very pretty , it does not look like a post, it looks like this:

Simply GridView:

[image]

And I wanted something like that:
The way I wanted it:

[image]

Do you have any way to do this?

If not, would I have to see the whole post click on the title and not the giant red button? Can not it be dark when I move the mouse? especially in pagination, like this: [HORRIBLE](https://i.imgur.com/Ws1G9Ke.gifv)

Code aspx :

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-page" id="conteudo">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gdv_posts" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gdv_posts_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gdv_posts_PageIndexChanging">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="titulo" HeaderText="Titulo" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="descrição" HeaderText="Descrição" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="data" HeaderText="Data de Criação" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="autor" HeaderText="Autor" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_visualizar" runat="server" Text="Visualizar" class="btn btn-danger" CommandName="Visualizar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' />  
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
       </div>  
      </div> 
     </div>
```

Code cs:

```html
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gdv_posts.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                preencherGrid();
            }
        }
        
        
        protected void gdv_posts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gdv_posts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            preencherGrid();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<asp:GridView/>` is basically a plain table int html. If you would like your posts to look like in the image supplied you would need a table of 1 column and X rows. To accomplish that you should use one `<asp:TemplateField/>` with an `<ItemTemplate/>` inside. And then design the content inside to your liking.

Example:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gdv_posts" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gdv_posts_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gdv_posts_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "titulo")%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "descrição")%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "data")%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "autor")%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```